# Include my header files

Tags: c++, library

let's suppose I have folder called AES, in this folder is file "AES.ino" where is code and folder "AESLib" what is library. In "AESLib" is file called "AESLib.h",

now when I try to include AESLib.h with

```
#include "AESLib/AESLib.h"
```

in my AES.ino, then Arduino command line tool complain that its not able to find "AESLib.h"

Where could be the catch?

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed `AESLib` as a library, according to the [official instructions](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries)?

Comment: Hi Peter, including code as Arduino custom library is another approach and of course working.  But this is about including your custom code, without use "library approach"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this similar post is what you are looking for. In your case, you should use the path to the sketch folder as 'PROJECT_ROOT'.

Here's the link:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/9575/7741

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using the Arduino IDE 1.5.6 beta.
Adding the library(s) using the menu (Sketch->include library->something) makes it work until the IDE is closed.